# Returning checked items from multi-choice dialog

Tags: java, android

By reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), I have managed to create a multiple choice dialog box. However, there's one bit that still has me completely stumped. When the user clicks "Okay", how do I return them to the parent Activity?

I"m referring to this particular comment:

```
 // Set the action buttons
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
               // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
               ...
           }
```

How exactly would I 'return them to the component that opened the dialog'?

My dialog call in my activity:

```
 public void chooseTeam(View v) {;
    DialogFragment newDialog = MultiChoiceDialog.newInstance(teamNamesArray);
    newDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Choose_team");

}
```

and my dialog code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String[] team = getArguments().getStringArray("team");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.choose_team).setMultiChoiceItems(team, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                list.add(team[which]);
            } else if (list.contains(team[which])) {
                list.remove(team[which]);
            }
        }
    }).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String selections = "";
            for (String ms : list) {
                selections = selections + "\n" + ms;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Team Selected: " + selections,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AddTaskActivity.chosenTeam =  list;
        }
    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: I think that I could create a variable `public static ArrayList<String> checkedItems` in the parent activity and simply say that `myActivity.checkedItems = mSelectedItems` but that sounds...wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make the ArrayList a class member variable like `private ArrayList mSelectedItems;`

See example code below

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList mSelectedItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            // Set the dialog title
            builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_toppings)
                    // Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
                    // and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
                    .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.toppings, null,
                            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                                    boolean isChecked) {
                                    if (isChecked) {
                                        // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                                        mSelectedItems.add(which);
                                    } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                                        // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                        mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            // Set the action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                            // or return them to the component that opened the dialog

// in this case the OK button has more or less no function but if want save the check options in database or shared preference, you can put your code here. So it depends on your use case.

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I have my `MultiChoiceDialog` in its' own class, I apologise for not mentioning that. I'll attach snippets of my actual project code, one sec

Comment: If the class is an inner class to your activity file, you can as well use the same method as the code above but if it is and independent class, you can create a setter method in you activity class and pass the array as a parameter.

Comment: I am really confused by the 'listArray' in that documentation. I have a layout which contains a checkbox. I need to respond to that checkbox. However, if I just make a list of strings containing  getString(R.string.show_password) from android:text="@string/show_password" of my check box, I get TWO checkboxes in my Dialog. I have no idea what is going on.'